# delphi helper functions in variant records

Tags: delphi

Delphi 10.2: I have a variant record definition:

```
type
  TIPMCCmdPacket = packed record
    TransactionID: Word;
    FuncCode: Word;
    DataLen: Word;
    case byte of
         //raw data buffer
      0: (RawBuf: Array[0..16383] of Byte);
         //error response
      1: (ErrCode: Word;                            //error type code
          ErrLen: Word;                             //length of error msg/data
          ErrBuf: Array[0..16379] of AnsiChar);     //err msg buffer
         //normal response, usually an ansistring
      2: (BufCnt: Word;                             //byte count
          Buffer: Array[0..16381] of Byte);         //response data
         //structured-data response
      3: (RecType: Word;                            //type code of record 
          RecCnt: Word;                             //# of records
          RecSize: Word;                            //size of each record
          RecBuf: Array[0..16377] of Byte);         //data block
  end;
```

I want to add a couple helper functions to this, but the normal syntax for record helpers throws syntax errors when used on variant records, and the language reference doesn't mention the case of using helpers with a variant record.  Is there a way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: By "record helpers", I suspect you mean member functions and procedures. (["Record helpers"](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Class_and_Record_Helpers_(Delphi)) is a different concept.)

Comment: I completely forgot that that syntax works on records as well as classes.  Thanks!

Comment: The really useful thing about record helpers is that they can be used on non-class types which are not records: integer types, arrays, etc. That way you can give such types "member functions". We all use `TIntegerHelper` and `TStringHelper` daily. (I use `TIntegerHelper` in my A!)

Comment: That's a habit I haven't gotten into, because I never do anything but Windows/VCL development and haven't had to be concerned with the differences in string indexing and the like, and I've been using the traditional functions for 35 years.  But it's a habit I need to develop.

Comment: Indeed! I also only develop for Windows using the VCL.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that the variant part of a record must be the last part of the record, while fields are not allowed below methods and properties in a list of members. This makes it hard to combine the two features. However, there are various ways to effectively circumvent this limitation.

**Method 1: Dummy record**

You can use a dummy record for the variant part:

```
type
  TTest = record
    Name: string;
    Age: Integer;
    Dummy: record
      case Byte of
        0: (Data: Integer);
        1: (Tag: Byte);
    end;
    procedure Test;
  end;
```

This has the visible effect that you need to write `t.Dummy.Data` instead of `t.Data`.

**Method 2: Record helper**

If that is not acceptable, you can use a [record helper](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Class_and_Record_Helpers_(Delphi)):

```
type
  TTest = record
    Name: string;
    Age: Integer;
    case Byte of
        0: (Data: Integer);
        1: (Tag: Byte);
  end;

  TTestHelper = record helper for TTest
    procedure Test;
  end;

procedure TTestHelper.Test;
begin
  ShowMessage(Name);
  ShowMessage(Age.ToString);
  ShowMessage(Data.ToHexString);
end;
```

**Method 3: Use a visibility keyword as a separator**

[David Heffernan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan) suggested in a comment that you can use the `public` visibility keyword to circumvent the syntactic limitation you are observing. By using this keyword, you can write

```
type
  TTest = packed record
    procedure Test;
  public
    Name: string;
    Age: Integer;
    case Byte of
        0: (Data: Integer);
        1: (Tag: Byte);
  end;
```

which has no unwanted side effects. This is because the default visibility is public, so all members are public -- both before and after `public`.

Comment: How about using public to break up the sections?

Comment: @David: Indeed, that's even neater. You can post that as an A so you get the credit for it.

Comment: If you could do it that would be cool. I'm busy right now. Don't much care about the credit.